# cloning or backing up Windows 7 installations

Tags: windows-7, backup, clone

It occurred to be today that my two windows computers have years of work on them, and that I need to back them up. I'm not really concerned with backing up data per se, but I am looking at the way I set up the operating system with scripts, automation, applications etc and wanted to know if I can simply clone my OS with Windows 7

I pretty much want a perfect byte for byte snapshot of my machine, but was worried that if Windows 7 crashed and I had to reinstall the OS (something I dread)

***how would I get back all that work I did on the OS?***

I know we can make Windows backups of certain folders, but it is my understanding this would not re-install the software I have installed.

***Would my Windows verification work if I clone my OS to another drive, or is it hardware dependent?***

It might be worth mentioning that on one machine I have the serials keys, and the other I do not as I bought it second hand and never wrote down the serials.

Comment: Windows doesn't have a way to clone your installation built-in, to do that, you need third-part software.  Most people create an image of their hdd.

Comment: As Ramhoud says: there is software that creates an image file (similar to an ISO file) which is a byte perfect copy of your harddrive. The space of such image without compression is the same size of your entire harddrive used bytes. But when something happens, you can boot off their rescue media to restore the image.

Comment: Would my Windows verification work if I clone my OS to another drive, or is it hardware dependent?

Comment: CloneZilla is an easy, free tool that can create a bit for bit image of your system. You can restore it to another hard drive and if Windows needs to reactivate, you'll be able to do so without issue. If you restore to a different *computer*, that's another issue, because your Windows license is most likely tied to your original motherboard and cannot be moved to another machine.

Comment: Ok thank you. This is the information i needed. The OS is tied to motherboard

Comment: Not with Acronis it isn't.  You don't even need the product key.  HOWEVER, I highly recommend you run Belarc Advisor under Windows and print it out.  Among all the other information it prints the installation keys of a lot of software, including Win7.

Answer (score -1):

I use Acronis True Image 2017 for this.  It can clone disks or make total system backups.  Or just single partitions, or even just a directory.

Restores are simple.  If it is just a directory you drill down into the boot image as if it were a hard drive and fetch whatever you need.

With the bootable media I can restore the whole system to a completely blank disk.

It even claims it can restore to dissimilar hardware, but I haven't tried that.  The bootable media is Linux and doesn't seem picky about what the hardware is as long as the drives are big enough to hold what you are trying to restore.  It keeps all the partitions and the boot loader, so I an restore both Win7 and Ubuntu if the primary drive fails.

Well worth the peace of mind.